# Developing an iterate algorithm which returns splices of even distance apart

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm looking at writing code which will return splices of an image (or any vector/array) with a selected number of frames `N` of set length `L`.

For example, If I have an a list of size 254, and I want to return 4 frames that are length 64, I will return indices `0:63`, `63:127`, `127:189`, `189:253`.

For a more difficult example, if the list size is 254 and I want to return 7 frames that are length 64, how can I go about writing some sort of generator that will return 7 splices of length 64 which are evenly distributed to cover all indices?

An example of some pseudocode:

```
overlap = ?? ## calculate overlap here
vector = [] ## insert vector of length 254

for i in range(0, len(vector) - 64 - 1, overlap): ## final index must be length of vector minus 64
     yield vector[i : i + 64]
```

Comment: I don't understand, the length of 0:63 is 64 but the length of 63:127 and 127:191 is 65 also the length of 191:253 is 63!! Why? You said the length of each frame should be 64!

Comment: I made the correction. That was obviously a textual error and doesn't actually change the question in any way.

Comment: It's unclear. If total length is 10, frame length is 3, frame count is 4, what's the correct answer that you are looking for?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, (not using indices here for simplification) so if the length is 10, then the first window would be 1-3 last one would be 7-10 and the two windows would be in between so that they cover the other frames and the remaining indices evenly. This would leave us with 4 frames, each frame being 3 units long.